# How to "mle_tuple" returned by "scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit" to sample from a distribution(python/scipy)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, scipy.stats

I have gotten a result from fitting my data using(scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit):

```
'exponweib': (10.92, 0.64,-0.91,2.816)
'genextreme': (-0.194, 10.92, 7.01),
'beta': (0.72,65.760,1.01999,862.270)
```

[image: What I found on]

I want to sample from each distribution after creating it using these parameters using python.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the tuple into the rvs method, like so: `stats.beta.rvs(*mle_tuple, size=10)`  and so on